# Create dynamic rules from list in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a list of ips in tf

```
ips = ["1.2.3.1/32", "1.2.3.2/32", "1.2.3.3/32", "1.2.3.4/32", "1.2.3.5/32", "1.2.3.6/32" ]
```

The rule:

```
resource "aws_alb_listener_rule" "test" {
  listener_arn = aws_alb_listener.https.arn
  priority     = 4

  action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.test.arn
  }

  condition {
    host_header {
      values = ["test"]
    }
  }

  condition {
    path_pattern {
      values = [
      "/somepath"]
    }
  }

  condition {
    source_ip {
      values = var.ips
    }
  }
}
```

Now I have to create a listener rule for this ALB. I faced some issue that you can only have a max of 5 conditions for a listener rule.

I can get it working by splitting the list in 2 and creating 2 rules, one pointing to `ips_1` and the second rule uses `ips_2`

```
ips_1 = ["1.2.3.1/32", "1.2.3.2/32", "1.2.3.3/32"]
ips_2 = ["1.2.3.4/32", "1.2.3.5/32", "1.2.3.6/32"]
```

Now the issue is that I have to create a new variable (`ips_3`) when a new IP will be added because I have the max of 5 conditions now for each rule.

so I want to keep one list:

```
ips = ["1.2.3.1/32", "1.2.3.2/32", "1.2.3.3/32", "1.2.3.4/32", "1.2.3.5/32", "1.2.3.6/32"]
```

How can I make this more dynamic so:

- create a rule for every 3 items (ips) of the variable so I will end up with 2 rules now and if I add a variable I will get a 3th rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`chunklist`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/chunklist.html) to chunk up a list into a list of lists of size `n`.

As an example, the following Terraform:

```
variable "ips" {
  default = ["1.2.3.1/32", "1.2.3.2/32", "1.2.3.3/32", "1.2.3.4/32", "1.2.3.5/32", "1.2.3.6/32"]
}

output "ips_chunked" {
  value = chunklist(var.ips, 3)
}
```

will output this:

```
ips_chunked = tolist([
  tolist([
    "1.2.3.1/32",
    "1.2.3.2/32",
    "1.2.3.3/32",
  ]),
  tolist([
    "1.2.3.4/32",
    "1.2.3.5/32",
    "1.2.3.6/32",
  ]),
])
```

So in your use case you could iterate over the chuked list, passing in the child lists to each rule:

```
variable "ips" {
  default = ["1.2.3.1/32", "1.2.3.2/32", "1.2.3.3/32", "1.2.3.4/32", "1.2.3.5/32", "1.2.3.6/32"]
}

resource "aws_alb_listener_rule" "test" {
  for_each = toset(chunklist(var.ips))

  listener_arn = aws_alb_listener.https.arn

  action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.test.arn
  }

  condition {
    host_header {
      values = ["test"]
    }
  }

  condition {
    path_pattern {
      values = [
        "/somepath"
      ]
    }
  }

  condition {
    source_ip {
      values = each.value
    }
  }
}
```

The above Terraform will split the `var.ips` list into chunks of 3, creating a load balancer listener rule for each block of 3 and then each rule will have 3 IP addresses in it.

Note that I also removed the hardcoded [`priority` argument](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lb_listener_rule#priority) in the rule to allow Terraform to automatically increment the rule priority for each load balancer listener rule instead of you having to calculate what they should be when iterating over them:

> `priority` - (Optional) The priority for the rule between `1` and `50000`. Leaving it unset will automatically set the rule with next available priority after currently existing highest rule. A listener can't have multiple rules with the same priority.

Comment: Thanks, I was just trying a bit with chuncklist. I'm not using for_each atm because I have to define the count to define the priority. Any idea how I should define my values = xxx when I'm using a count? count = length(chunklist(var.ips,3))

Comment: Do you _need_ the priority? If you don't specify it then it will default to using the next available priority number. Unless you're doing particularly complex things that _should_ be enough in most case. We have load balancer listener rules with hundred of dynamically created rules and have never had an issue with just using the next one. It would only be an issue if you had potentially overlapping conditions and want to set priority between those but I'd instead try to avoid that being a possibility by making the rules exclusive.

Comment: I was thinking about something like values = [chunklist(var.ips,3)[count.index]]

Comment: This is probably bordering on new question territory if you have an extra constraint where you can expand on that.

Comment: Got it working with count. Of course your solution is better (so accepted as correct answer) but I had to follow some restrictions.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, as of Terraform 1.05, I get the following error:
for_each = toset(chunklist(local.addresses, 5))
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.addresses is tuple with 6 elements
│ 
│ The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: "for_each" supports maps
│ and sets of strings, but you have provided a set containing type list of
│ string.